# Is there a name for this particular programming challenge, and what can we do better that O(N^2)?

Tags: algorithm

Here is the problem. There are N people, one of them is king. Everybody knows the king while the king knows no one. Is there a name or some theory on how to best find out the number of the king is this case given that we have a function that determines if person i knows person j. Of course we could simply for each person check first which ones do not know anyone and then check which one of those is known by everyone. But this is order N^2 and I am curious if there is something faster. Thanks in advance

Comment: Make that a graph. The node that represents the king has 0 outgoing edges and N - 1 incoming edges.

Comment: @Cicada - If you are given the graph in advance, then that is a good solution.  If not, then it is O(N^2) to construct the graph.

Comment: @mbeckish I just gave the data structure, not the algorithm to find the king :)

Comment: @Cicada - Yes, but just the act of constructing that data structure already puts you at O(N^2).

Comment: @mbeckish You don't have to construct anything, just see the problem as a *graph* problem. It doesn't matter how the input data is stored, it can always be mapped as a graph (as does the answer to this question).

Comment: @Cicada - It all depends on how the data is given to you, which is why my first comment said that if you are given the graph, then it would be worthwhile to use it in your algorithm.  If not, then it won't help, because mapping it to a graph will be O(N^2), before you've even started solving it.

Comment: @mbeckish I'll reword: can you imagine an input where the data is *not*, de facto, a graph?

Comment: @mbeckish - The data as given is already a graph.  There is no need to build a new structure.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this in `O(n)` time. Imagine a ballroom with all of the people including the king. We'll call them `1` through `n`. Visit person `1`. Ask if they know person `2` -- if not, `3`, and so on. The first person they do know, person `v`, visit and ask them if they know person `v + 1`, if not `v + 2`, and so on. Then visit the first person they know. Keep doing this until you've asked about (and possibly visited) `n`.

Since everyone knows the king, one of these people will have directed you to the king who knows nobody else, and thus the king can't refer you to anyone else. After you get to asking about the last person, person `n`, you will be talking to the king.

Roughly:

```
int find_king() {
    int visiting = 1;
    for (int asking_about = 2; asking_about <= n; asking_about++) {
        if (knows(visiting, asking_about)) {
            visiting = asking_about;
        }
    }
    return visiting;
}
```

Comment: Edited so we don't ask 1 if they know themselves.